# TypeError: TypeErro...pected',)

Tags: python, tensorflow

TypeError: TypeErro...pected',) in converting string type tensor to float32 and initialize to constant tensor.
Value reading from a file is received as string type so need to convert to float32.

How can I make it work?

```
filename, label, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8 = tf.decode_csv(value, [[''], [''], [''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],['']], ' ')
boxes = tf.constant([tf.dtypes.cast(box1, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box2, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box3, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box4, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box5, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box6, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box7, tf.float32),tf.dtypes.cast(box8, tf.float32)])
```

Error is

```
TypeError: TypeErro...pected',)
```

Comment: In the future, please don't abbreviate important parts of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Used tf.stack and solved.

```
boxes = tf.transpose(tf.stack([tf.strings.to_number(box1,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box2,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box3,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box4,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box5,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box6,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box7,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box8,tf.dtypes.float32)]))
```